# `element[attribute=value] element .class` selector is not applied

Tags: css

I want colors marked as `.light` disappear from 2nd `select` when black background is set,
what is wrong with my CSS?

```css
body[data-background="Black"] {
  background: black
}
body[data-background="Black"] option .light {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].setAttribute('data-background', this.value)">
  <option>White</option>
  <option>Black</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>Green</option>
  <option class="light">darkBlue</option>
  <option class="light">Indigo</option>
  <option>Purple</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Remove the space between `option` and `.light `

Comment: @vaultah Huh, I thought CSS is space-insensitive...

Comment: Nope, space is only required for descendant selector. Space is removed for multiple class selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `option .light` it means something with class light **inside** option tag

Try to replace it with "option.light"

[**Reference**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors)

> At times, authors may want selectors to match an element that is the
>   descendant of another element in the document tree (e.g., "Match those
>   EM elements that are contained by an H1 element"). Descendant
>   selectors express such a relationship in a pattern. A descendant
>   selector is made up of two or more selectors **separated by white
>   space**. A descendant selector of the form "A B" matches when an
>   element B is an arbitrary descendant of some ancestor element A.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `.light` class for `<option>` not for its child. So use:

```
body[data-background="Black"] option.light {
  display: none !important;
}
```